# Dragging composite objects in Unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am writing a card game in Unity2D that requires dragging a card to a table that has fixed positions.
The card is a composite gameobject that contains these items:

- Parent -> Empty
- BG -> Image
- MID -> Image
- FG -> Image
- Values -> Text

I want to be able to drag the card to the table and remove it from the player's hand.
While i have found some implementations of drag/drop they all seem to rely on dragging a single image and not a gameobject.
What can i use to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything? OnMouseDrag?

Comment: I tried using the Unity UI Sample Scripts but they create an icon to drag, since my image is composed by different layers i need to move the whole gameobject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler` interfaces in your script that is attached to the draggable game object.

```
public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
    // Set parent to a RectTransform that is in front of everything else 
    this.transform.SetParent(draggablesRoot);
}

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
    this.transform.position = eventData.position;
}

public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
    // Use "EventSystem.current.RaycastAll()" to detect whether the object was dropped onto the correct panel
}
```